# Not working: .where("bezeichnung or nummer like ?", "%#{search}%")

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I wrote a little search query in rails:

```
.where("bezeichnung or nummer like ?", "%#{search}%")
```

It somehow wont work corectly, i dont get a error but it seems like it only makes a search query on the `nummer` field. Then i tried:

```
.where("bezeichnung like ?", "%#{search}%")
```

With the same search param i got a lot more recors. What did i wrong? Thanks

Comment: Anybody know why this wouldn't generate a SQL error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match on two terms with an `or` using a single `where` call, you'll need to pass the `search` to both clauses, and separate them with the `or`:

```
.where("bezeichnung LIKE ? OR nummer LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: Do you know why the OP's original code wouldn't generate an SQL error?

Comment: Likely because it evaluates to something like `true or nummer like ?`